# Looking for a (pseudo-)scientific description of Lot's wife turning into a pillar of salt

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking for a short story that gives a pseudo-scientific explanation for the biblical story of Lot's wife getting turned into a pillar of salt when fleeing Sodom and looking back.

I *think* the premise that the author was accidentally invited to speak at a science conference, for which he wrote the story as a medical case study of an extreme case of dehydration and electrolyte imbalance, caused by the shock the poor victim experienced by seeing her old home and city being destroyed. The case study ends with a quote of Genesis 19:26.

> But Lot's wife looked back, and she became a pillar of salt.

Only then we learn the story is about the wife of Lot.

The story then concludes with something along the lines of

> Needless to say, I was laughed out of the room.

---

I *thought* it was written by Asimov, but I can't find it in lists of his short stories. It *may* have been a collection compiled by him.

I read it in the mid-nineties, but it's probably older, as I'm pretty sure I read in a book that belonged to either my uncle or my grandfather.

Of course I've turned to Google, but to no avail.

Comment: [Rain, Rain, Go Away](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rain,_Rain,_Go_Away_(short_story))?

Comment: It can't be [this story](http://danielkason.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/lots-wife.html), as that's more recent than the 90s.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

"**[A singular case of extreme electrolyte balance associated with folie a deux](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?93395)**" by Robert D. Tschirgi, as seen in *[Worm Runner's Digest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worm_Runner%27s_Digest)*, 1965, VII(2), pp. 78-79.

> Some pieces require a faint familiarity with other classics of literature and science. *"A singluar [sic] case of extreme electrolyte balance assocviated [sic] with folie a deux"* uses the style of a clinical report to describe why Lot's wife became a pillar of salt.

I have not yet found the actual date of the entry (or other references to the content), but the journal started in 1959 and ended in 1979, so it fits the timeframe. One place it was reprinted is *[Science, Sex, and Sacred Cows](http://drpatreads.blogspot.com/2016/10/spoofing-science-before-ig-nobel-prize.html)*. Another is *[11th Annual Edition: The Year's Best S-F](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?34893)*.

Found with a search for `science fiction "lot's wife" electrolyte imbalance`

**user14111** has confirmed the ending. After quoting *Genesis* XIX, 24–26, the last line is:

> *I am pleased to report*, Dr. Tschirgi's note concludes, *that I was laughed off the podium.*

Comment: "A Singular Case of Extreme Electrolyte Balance Associated with Folie a Deux (1965) by Robert D. Tschirgi "- is also in a few SciFi anthologies (eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Year's_Best_S-F_11th_Annual_Edition_(Judith_Merril_anthology))

Comment: NB - this does appear to be a reprint of the same too (I just wanted to give the author credit): http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?93395

Comment: @SeanR - Better now?

Comment: You're absolutely right. I forgot to amend my answer after SeanR provided that link.

Comment: Yes, that's it. I've read it in *The Year's Best S-F*. Thank you. *How* did you find it? I've searched for numerous combinations of `pillar of salt` and `electrolyte`.

Comment: *science fiction "lot's wife" electrolyte imbalance*. My third result or so was to "http://paperfrigate.blogspot.com/2005_06_01_archive.html". A search on the title brought up the drpatreads.blogspot.com entry, which mentioned it came from the Worm Runner's Digest. I published as much, then started adding info from comments. :)

Comment: I figured the "lot's wife" would be the most likely unique bit, and I lucked out with adding "electrolyte imbalance" as the clinical bit.